# C# async await (try/)catch fails in .NET 6

Tags: c#, async-await, try-catch, .net-6.0

The following code works as expected in (the code-behind of a WPF `UserControl` of a **.NET 4.8** project).

```
    private async Task DeleteAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            await ViewModel.DeleteAsync(GetSelectedItems());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var doCatch = ex is ValidationException
                || ex is ExpectedInfoException
                || ex is ExpectedDbException;
            if (doCatch)
                ExeptionHelper.HandleException(ex, AppConstants.ApplicationName);
            else
                throw;
        }
    }
```

The following analog experiment does not always Catch an exception in a .NET 6.0 project, see inline comments.
My attempt of a minimal reproducible repro sample is still not complete yet, but hopefully someone already has an educated guess for the reason?

```
        private async void DeleteListAsync()
        {
            var list = ViewModel.GetSelectedItems(
                dataGrid.SelectedItems.OfType<ActorModel>().ToList());
            try
            {
                await ViewModel.DeleteListAsync(list);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) when (
                ex is ValidationException
                || ex is ExpectedInfoException
                || ex is ExpectedDbException)
            {
                /* this part does run as expected when() one of those three 
                 * custom MyNamespace.Exceptions gets thrown in the previous `try` block.
                 * But unexpectedly *not when thrown inside the nested step-into code of 
                 * ViewModel.DeleteListAsync() */
                ApplicationHelper.HandleException(ex, Intl.LocalizedConstants.AppName);
            }
            catch
            {
                /* this part does run as expected when a `new InvalidOperationException("Test")`
                 * or `NotImplementedException()` gets thrown directly in the `try`block.
                 * Also when thrown inside the nested step-into code of 
                 * ViewModel.DeleteListAsync() */
                throw;
            }
        }
```

[Solved]: Much later, with the help of the useful comments I actually found a missing await statement in a secluded and dark corner of the nested code, just as @Charlieface said, thank you all very much!

Comment: Can you please add [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I'm not sure what the difference is here between .NET 6 and 4.8, but if you add `catch (AggregateException aex) {...}` it'll likely work. Your `ValidationException` will be in `aex.InnerExceptions`.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for the input, @rfmodulator Throwing a `System.AggregateException`  instead of the custom one does not seem to make a difference at first glance, but I'll keep it in mind while working on my minimal repro attempt

Comment: `AggregateException` is what .net (usually?) throws when a `Task` has an exception, and it contains the actual exception. You wouldn't throw that exception yourself; your nested code will stay the same, you will just catch that exception type... you can `catch (Exception ex)` for debugging and see what's really happening.

Comment: It's weird that you're getting an `AggregateException` anyway, as `await` is supposed to unwrap it. Perhaps somewhere there is code that does not use `await`

Comment: `catch (Exception ex)` also does not catch the custom exception thrown in the nested code, and no `AggregateException` appears. Will continue struggling with my minimal repro attempt

Comment: So the `DeleteAsync` method swallows all exceptions, and logs only `ValidationException`s? You have a weird setup there. Do you invoke the `DeleteAsync` method in a fire-and-forget fashion?

Comment: Side note: `.ConfigureAwait(true)` is the default, so you don't need to include it.

Comment: I edited the question as a feedback attempt to the comments. @GabrielLuci, the `.ConfigureAwait(true)` were orphans of once having  used the deprecated `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers` Nuget extension.

Comment: In your second `catch` block, change it to `catch (Exception ex)`, set a breakpoint inside and inspect the actual type of `ex` (`ex.GetType()`) - what is it?

Comment: @rfmodulator `await` will unwrap and rethrow the first inner exception of an `AggregateException`, so you don't have to manually handle that one if you use `await` (but you will need to if you use things like `Wait()` or `Result` on the task).

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel I'm not sure what's causing this behavior, why it worked in 4.8 but not in 6.0.

Comment: It's going to be impossible to tell without putting a breakpoint in that catch and checking the exception type.

Comment: Problem solved, with the help of the useful comments I actually found a missing `await` statement in a secluded and dark corner of the nested code, thank you all very much! @Charlieface, thanks for your input, yours was exactly the "educated guess" I had been hoping for. So if you and also @rfmodulator, @GabrielLuci and @EtiennedeMartel would post your input as an answer before this thread is getting closed, I would upvote those and accept.

Comment: @GuruStron, I found the reason as a missing `await` on a lower floor of the nested code, so there won't be no minimal repro code, sorry. Perhaps the question should not get closed/removed though, because I think the solution could be useful for one or another person who would hit the same issue. Personally I was surprised the compiler did not complain about my stupid mistake, and no Info or Warning in the `Error List` window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You apparently have a missing `await` somewhere in your code, which is causing an exception to be wrapped in an `AggregateException`.

One of the things that `await` does, as well as setting up the state machinery, is to unwrap `AggregateExceptions` which hold any exceptions that were thrown during the running of the `Task`. Therefore, if you want to catch and handle a specific exception type, you should use `await` all the way down.

Comment: "Closed. This question needs debugging details. It is not currently accepting answers.
Edit the question to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem. This will help others answer the question.
Closed 13 days ago.
The community reviewed whether to reopen this question 13 days ago and left it closed:
    Original close reason(s) were not resolved
(Private feedback for you)" Quelle dommage, that sounds to me as if "The community" did not read very carefully

Comment: You still don't have "shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem", I solved it with a guess. The fact that it got answered doesn't really help others, as you aren't showing what went wrong and what was fixed

Comment: We were guessing together as a team :) _"I actually found a missing await statement in a secluded and dark corner of the nested code, thank you all very much!"_ Now who would want to know where that forgotten 'await' was exactly and how it was looking. and how I found it exactly. The surprising gotcha at least for me is that a missing `await` in front of an `async` call may not necessarily cause a compiler or "Error List" remark when there also is a trailing `.ConfigureAwait(false)` but instead cause a `catch` not to get triggered

Comment: Yes others will want to see it, but obviously not the full code. It's called creating a [mcve], stressing in particular the *minimal* bit, so that others looking at the question can understand what's going on. Talking about a problem/solution is often nowhere near as good as showing it

Comment: Hmm, okay, I'll think about how such a surprise demo might be _minimally looking_ :)